# Django model will auto index pk and unique_together, how can I cancel it?

Tags: django, django-models

As far as I know, Django will auto index the "pk" and "unique" field...

But Now, My Django version is 1.8, and I want to use brin index. but I can't find

any way to migrate let my all index remove, then I can custom index by myself.

thanks.

Comment: Simply explicitly write `db_index=False`.

Comment: Note that `ForeignKey`s have `db_index`es by default as well, and `ManyToMany` field construct a "hidden" table, again with indexes.

Comment: thanks, If I don't have FK, I just needs to db_index=False in pk and unique filed !!!

Comment: Django will automagically created and index a field if none are specific with `primary_key=True`; can you show us the model you're working on? Are you specifying a primary key?